# Why this java recursive method not creating infinite loop?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development, while trying to read a code example, I encountered a method which is being called from within itself, so logically it should create an infinite loop of calling itself. But it does not. why?

In my `MainActivity.java`

```
 public void onWishlistSelected() {
        launchUserSpecificFragment(new WishlistFragment(), WishlistFragment.class.getSimpleName(), new LoginDialogInterface() {
            @Override
            public void successfulLoginOrRegistration(User user) {
                // If login was successful launch WishlistFragment.
                onWishlistSelected(); // Why doesn't this create infine loop?
            }
        });
    }
```

and calling it:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_wish_list) {
            onWishlistSelected();
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.action_cart) {
            onCartSelected();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**EDIT**

Here is the code inside `launchUserSpecificFragment`

```
   private void launchUserSpecificFragment(Fragment fragment, String transactionTag, LoginDialogInterface loginListener) {
        if (SettingsMy.getActiveUser() != null) {
            replaceFragment(fragment, transactionTag);
        } else {
            DialogFragment loginDialogFragment = LoginDialogFragment.newInstance(loginListener);
            loginDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), LoginDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName());
        }
    }
```

and `replaceFragment`

```
 private void replaceFragment(Fragment newFragment, String transactionTag) {
        if (newFragment != null) {
            FragmentManager frgManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = frgManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setAllowOptimization(false);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(transactionTag);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_content_frame, newFragment).commit();
            frgManager.executePendingTransactions();
        } else {
            Timber.e(new RuntimeException(), "Replace fragments with null newFragment parameter.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`onWishlistSelected` is **not** calling itself, so there is not infinite recursion here.

It is calling `launchUserSpecificFragment`, which receives an instance of an anonymous class implementing `LoginDialogInterface` as an argument.

The anonymous class contains a `successfulLoginOrRegistration` method that calls `onWishlistSelected`, but calling `onWishlistSelected` doesn't necessarily execute that `successfulLoginOrRegistration` method. When `successfulLoginOrRegistration` will be executed depends on the logic of `launchUserSpecificFragment`.

Comment: so when it is called inside `successfulLoginOrRegistration` , why won't it call `launchUserSpecificFragment` again?

Comment: @RameshPareek You have to look into the code of `launchUserSpecificFragment` to see what it's doing. Otherwise there's no way of telling what it calls or doesn't call.

Comment: @RameshPareek it will. But then `successfulLoginOrRegistration` won't be called again, at least not immediately again.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the place where you call `onWishlistSelected` is inside an *anonymous class* and not directly in the `onWishlistSelected` method itself.

If you look closely that your call to `onWishlistSelected` is put inside a method called `successfulLoginOrRegistration`. This means that only when `successfulLoginOrRegistration` is called, `onWishlistSelected` is called.

So when will `successfulLoginOrRegistration` be called? I cannot know this from the amount of code you have given.

Now let's suppose that `successfulLoginOrRegistration` is called. As a result, `onWishlistSelected` is called, but then `onWishlistSelected` will only be called the next time `successfulLoginOrRegistration` is called.

Now you might ask, "Wouldn't the stack trace be filled with these two method calls?" The answer is probably not. `onWishlistSelected` will probably return first, so that other parts of the code is able to call `successfulLoginOrRegistration`. So the stack trace won't overflow.

I will use an easier-to-understand example to illustrate this:

```
private static JButton btn = new JButton("press me");
public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(btn);
    someMethod();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void someMethod() {
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("button pressed");
            someMethod();
        }
    });
}
```

This will not create an infinite loop. `someMethod` only executes when the user presses the button. When the user presses the button, `actionPerformed` is called and so is `someMethod`. But then nothing happens, until the user clicks the button again.

Comment: Kindly elaborate a bit more --**`OnwishSelected` will probably return first**' what does first mean here? Also I updated it with more relevant code, can you now help?

Comment: `onWishlistSelected` will return _first_, _then_ code from somewhere else will call `successfulLoginOrRegistration` at some unknown time (we can't know when even from the code you added. You need to find a method call named `successfulLoginOrRegistration`). After `successfulLoginOrRegistration` is called `onWishlistSelected` will be called again. @RameshPareek

Answer (score 0):

This method will never call infinitely reason is there is `successfulLoginOrRegistration` interface which is executing your `onWishlistSelected` method. In short your `onWishlistSelected` method will execute only when your `interface` will get callback in `successfulLoginOrRegistration`.

Answer (score 0):

onWishListSelected method is not calling itself. It defines a successfulLoginOrRegistration method but never calls it. This is what you want, I believe.

```
public void onWishlistSelected() {
        boolean loginSuccess = false; 
        launchUserSpecificFragment(new WishlistFragment(), WishlistFragment.class.getSimpleName(), new LoginDialogInterface() {
            @Override
            public void successfulLoginOrRegistration(User user) {
                // If login was successful launch WishlistFragment.
            }
            // set true when login successfully .
            // loginSuccess = true;
        });
        // call untill successfully logged in.
        if(loginSuccess == false){
          onWishlistSelected();
        }
}
```